# Can MapInfo ProViewer be installed on and be run from USB drive?

Tags: mapinfo, portable-gis

I am looking for a portable simple GIS.

Is it possible to install MapInfo ProViewer on a memory stick or DVD and run it from there, i.e. without requiring admin rights or installing any files (e.g. DLLs) on the machine?

Comment: What happened when you tried to do this?