# Any suggestions for a free simple portable GIS viewer

Tags: software-recommendations, portable-gis

I am looking for a free, simple and portable GIS viewer. Any suggestions?

By 'free', I mean gratis long-term, and not some trialware version or a version with 'restricted' functionality (e.g. < 1000 objects).

By 'simple' I mean a very basic, easy-to-use GIS viewer for a non-GIS user, like zooming, panning, identifying, switching on/off layers, etc. It still needs to be able to handle large data files though. Portable versions of ArcMap or QGIS are far too complex.

By 'portable' I mean a viewer that can be:

1. installed on a USB memory stick or on a DVD without needing any
   admin rights or without installing any files (e.g. DLLs) on the PC;
2. run from the memory stick or DVD

By 'viewer', I mean a GIS that doesn't allow creating, updating, or deleting the data.

I tried ArcGIS Explorer Desktop but didn't like it.

The whole point is that I can give my clients a memory stick with a GIS and the data on it, and he can just plug and play, and explore the data without having to bother his internal IT department for getting software installed.

Comment: What client applications are available? Do they have internet connectivity? You could build a totally disconnect leaflet application with copies of the Leaflet CSS and JS files, and have a GeoJSON file that the Leaflet application uses - but would require a web browser to view...

Comment: I second mapBaker's suggestion of looking into web-based map viewers. Many IT departments will not even let you run untrusted executable files without admin privileges, in addition to not allowing you to install them.

Comment: This also assumes the unused USB ports are not disabled, and will permit mounting the device.

Comment: Have you considering creating a geoPDF?  Users can turn layers on and off and identify feature attributes.

Comment: OpenJUMP core version is about 20MB but users can create, update, and delete data. I can't say how difficult it would be to disable the possibility to set layers editable. It feels like a small job.

Comment: Asking a more focussed question like http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/174438/115 here is fine but I think an open ended one like this is too broad and in [softwarerecs.se] territory. However it would be fine in the GIS Chat Room.

Comment: Did you try Tatuk GIS viewer ? - [Tatuj GIS](http://www.tatukgis.com/Downloads/TrialFreeVersions/Viewer.aspx)

Comment: @mapBaker: It's one direction I have considered, and my first attempt already failed due to the client's ActiveX restrictions, so not a path without its challenges.

Comment: @artwork21: I am currently using geoPDFs, but they are very restrictive when it comes to zooming and labelling. They are not very good if you want to show it both as an overview map and be able to zoom to the individual objects. The solution of geoPDFs work, but it lacks the x-factor.

Comment: @user30184 and Tatuj GIS: I shall have a look at OpenJUMP and the Tatuk Viewer.

Comment: OpenJUMP may be too close to QGIS even it is simple to run from USB stick because it is pure Java. Tatuk Viewer may match your needs better but I do not know if it can be run from USB without admin rights. Gaia 3 probably has rather similar features and restrictions than Tatuk Viewer http://www.thecarbonproject.com/Products/Gaia.

Comment: Tatuk GIS viewer 4.35 works (portable) without admin permissions (W7 64 bit tested) but You have to check if it supports your file type.

Comment: @Artec: that looks promising. I downloaded it from the Tatuk website, but it doesn't let me run the executable. But that's not an issue (yet), as I can try it to install it on my USB stick using my home PC. Once installed, I can just copy it between USB sticks.
Re. data format, I am not fussed as I can convert it to whichever format the portable GIS takes.

Comment: @user30184: I downloaded Gaia and tried to install it, but it insists installing it at C:\Program Files (x86)\TheCarbonProject\Gaia\ without any option to change it. This even happens when trying to install it from my USB stick.

Comment: It seems to start if you copy all the files from Program Files into USB stick.

Comment: If I remember Tatuk GIS need to run Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable installed on windows.

Comment: @Artec: thanks for the heads up. For most of our clients, which are large office-based organisations, this won't be a problem as the MSVCR will already be present on their PCs (I think).
I have managed to install Tatuk GIS Viewer on my USB drive and run it, and first signs are good. Cheers